# ASP.NET MVC IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have follwing erorr after I have published site in IIS 7.5 and i don't hnow what to do

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ProiectLicenta.MvcApplication'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="ProiectLicenta.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Global.asax file cannot find the code-behind class MvcApplication in namespace ProiectLicenta. Search your solution and find the ProiectLicenta.MvcApplication class. If you cannot find the class in your solution maybe it is in an external dll that you need to add to the project.

Comment: Code-behind is not the correct term in this phrase, as it explicitly refers to a code page that contains a class and event handlers for an ASPX page. This concept does not exist in MVC.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is still ASP.NET so everything that you have in web forms you have it in the mvc also :-) Also in the default MVC 2 template the Global.asax file has a code-behind file.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you accepted is incomplete. For the sake of others researching this problem in the future, I'll elaborate.

Literally, this means that ASP.NET couldn't locate the type 'ProiectLicenta.MvcApplication'.

This can happen for a number of reasons. In order of likelyhood (imho, of course), they are:

1. You are ignoring an error when building your site. If the assembly or project that contains `ProiectLicenta.MvcApplication` can not be compiled, then ASP.NET will not be able to locate any classes or other entities therein contained. Solution: correct all compiler errors and try again.
2. The class `ProiectLicenta.MvcApplication` is not explicitly declared with the correct access specifier. Remember, classes declared like

   class MyClass { ... }

   are private. You'll probably want to change the declaration to

   public class MyClass { ... }
3. You are deploying your site and not including the assembly (DLL) which defines the type `ProiectLicenta.MvcApplication`. Correct your deployment process and try again.